# EPPlus sBase64.replace not a function

Tags: epplus, asp.net-core-6.0

After upgrading a project from .Net Core 3.1 to 6.0 including upgrading EPPlus to 6.0.6.  I'm getting s64base.replace not a function when I attempt to export data to excel.  Looks like it's in the JS for EPPlus.  Worked fine when it was .Net Core 3.1 with EPPlus 5.4.0.

I should have included that this is a Blazor Project using the BlazorDownloadFile.

The EPPlus example shows using Byte Array, but according to JavaScript the replace function is only good on strings.  I did just attempt changing the byte array I was using to string; but, though it got passed the java script error, the downloaded file failed to open in Excel.

Odd it worked before the .net core 6 upgrade.

Comment: What if, you downgrade the `EPPlus nuget package to 5.4.0` keeping the `dotnet version 6`. Its not necessary that you have to upgrade the [`EPPlus nuget package to 6.0.6`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/). You can try this way if that works for you.

Comment: Didn't work, thanks anyway.  The weird thing is I can upgrade to Core 5 with all the latest and it works.  As soon as I upgrade to Core 6 is where the failure occurs.  Though MS insists nothing changed that would impact this, my guess is something with Microsoft.JSInterop changed with 6.

Comment: If that is the case you could submit this issue to their `GitHub` thread meanwhile you can continue with the working version.